# Static member with static mutex and thread-safety

Tags: multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, static-members

I have a template class similar to this one:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo {
    public:
        static void show () { 
            unique_lock<mutex> l {mtx};
            for (const auto& v : vec) {
                cout << v << endl;
            }
        }

        static void add (T s) { 
            unique_lock<mutex> l {mtx};
            vec.push_back (s);
        }

    private:
        static mutex mtx;
        static vector<T> vec;
};

template <typename T> mutex Foo<T>::mtx;
template <typename T> vector<T> Foo<T>::vec;
```

And usage of this class looks like this:

```
Foo<string>::add ("d");
Foo<string>::add ("dr");
Foo<string>::add ("dre");
Foo<string>::add ("drew");
Foo<string>::show ();
```

Could you tell me if this class is thread-safe? And if it is not, how to make a thread safe version?

If I understand it correctly when we have a class with member functions (not static) and mutex (not static), we prevent race condition of the single object which has been passed across threads, right? And when we have something similar to this we prevent race condition not for the object but for the class instead - in this case for particular type, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. Up and to a point.
 `mtx` is 'guarding' vec to ensure that the iteration  in `show()` can not be taking place while the vector is being modified during `add()`.

Consider calling it `vec_mtx` if that is its role.

Up and to a point? 
Firstly, your use doesn't (in fact) indicate any threading taking place so I don't (quite) know what you're trying to achieve.

For example if all those adds were taking place in one thread and show in another, your code (obviously) won't ensure that they have **all** taken place before show.
It will only ensure that (logically) it takes place either before all of them, strictly between two of them or after all of them.

Although not applicable to your use case if you retained references to string objects you passed in or used a type T with a 'shallow' copy constructor then you might be in trouble.

Consider Foo::add(buffer); and continue modifying buffer such that show() is executing in one thread while `strcat(buffer,.)` is executing on another and buffer is temporarily not '\0' terminated. Boom! Book a ticket to Seg Fault City (where the grass aint green and the girls aint pretty).

You need to look hard (real hard) at what data is being shared and how.
Almost all unqualified statements 'X is thread-safe' are false for all X.
You should always (always) qualify what uses they are safe for and/or how far their safety extends.
That goes 10 times for templates.

Almost all template 'guarantees' can be blown by using some kind of C array (or complex structure holding a pointer or referenced elsewhere, passing it into template in a thread here while smacking it about over there. Your efforts to make an internal copy will themselves be unsafe!

There's a recurring fallacy that if you share data through some kind of thread-safe exchange structure such as a queue you get some kind of thread-safe guarantee and you never need to think about it again and can go back to your single threaded thinking.

Here endeth the lesson.

**NB:** In theory `std::string` could be implemented on a memory starved environment that aggressively 'pools' copy strings in a way that exposes you to race conditions you haven't even imagined. Theory you understand.